# Can I pretty-print the DBIC_TRACE output in DBIx::Class?

Tags: sql, perl, formatting, dbix-class

Setting the DBIC_TRACE environment variable to true:

```
BEGIN { $ENV{DBIC_TRACE} = 1 }
```

generates very helpful output, especially showing the SQL query that is being executed, but the SQL query is all on one line.

Is there a way to push it through some kinda "sql tidy" routine to format it better, perhaps breaking it up over multiple lines? Failing that, could anyone give me a nudge into where in the code I'd need to hack to add such a hook? And what the best tool is to accept a badly formatted SQL query and push out a nicely formatted one?

"nice formatting" in this context simply means better than "all on one line". I'm not particularly fussed about specific styles of formatting queries

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[As of DBIx::Class 0.08124 it's built in.](http://blog.afoolishmanifesto.com/archives/1444)

Just set `$ENV{DBIC_TRACE_PROFILE}` to `console` or `console_monochrome`.

Answer (score 11):

From the documentation of DBIx::Class::Storage

> If DBIC_TRACE is set then trace information is produced (as when the
>   debug method is set).
>  ...
>
> debug
>  Causes trace information to be emitted on the debugobj
>   object. (or STDERR if debugobj has not specifically been set).
>
> debugobj
>  Sets or retrieves the object used for metric collection.
>   Defaults to an instance of DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics that is
>   compatible with the original method of using a coderef as a callback.
>   See the aforementioned Statistics class for more information.

In other words, you should set `debugobj` in that class to an object that subclasses [DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics). In your subclass, you can reformat the query the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

First, thanks for the pointers!  Partial answer follows ....

What I've got so far ... first some scaffolding:

```
# Connect to our db through DBIx::Class
my $schema = My::Schema->connect('dbi:SQLite:/home/me/accounts.db');

# See also BEGIN { $ENV{DBIC_TRACE} = 1 }
$schema->storage->debug(1);

# Create an instance of our subclassed (see below)
# DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics class
my $stats = My::DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics->new();

# Set the debugobj object on our schema's storage
$schema->storage->debugobj($stats);
```

And the definition of My::DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics being:

```
package My::DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics;

use base qw<DBIx::Class::Storage::Statistics>;
use Data::Dumper qw<Dumper>;
use SQL::Statement;
use SQL::Parser;

sub query_start {
    my ($self, $sql_query, @params) = @_;

    print "The original sql query is\n$sql_query\n\n";

    my $parser = SQL::Parser->new();
    my $stmt   = SQL::Statement->new($sql_query, $parser);
    #printf "%s\n", $stmt->command;

    print "The parameters for this query are:";
    print Dumper \@params;
}
```

Which solves the problem about how to hook in to get the SQL query for me to "pretty-ify".

Then I run a query:

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('SomeTable')->search(
    {   
        'email' => $email,
        'others.some_col' => 1,
    },
    { join => 'others' }
);
$rs->count;
```

However SQL::Parser barfs on the SQL generated by DBIx::Class:

```
The original sql query is
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM some_table me LEFT JOIN others other_table ON ( others.some_col_id = me.id ) WHERE ( others.some_col_id = ? AND email = ? )

SQL ERROR: Bad table or column name '(others' has chars not alphanumeric or underscore!

SQL ERROR: No equijoin condition in WHERE or ON clause
```

So ... is there a better parser than SQL::Parser for the job?

Comment: I don't think there is, but SQL::Parser seems to be in active development (last update was Feb 6 this year).  You should make sure you've got the latest version, and if it still breaks, contact the module maintainer and report your bug: http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=SQL-Statement

Comment: There's a brand-new module on CPAN called SQL::Beautify: SQL::Beautify - 
Article:
http://annocpan.org/dist/SQL-Beautify Maybe it does what you need.